# Running Exe in Firefox why do I get an error

Tags: javascript, firefox

I run this in Firefox, when clicking on link, Firefox says NS_ERROR_FILE_UNRECOGNIZED_PATH wheread I followed the instruction from here [How to open .EXE with Javascript/XPCOM as Windows "Run..."?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177583/how-to-open-exe-with-javascript-xpcom-as-windows-run)

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function RunExe(path) {
    try {            
        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (ua.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
            MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
            MyObject.Run(path);
        } else {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");

            var exe = window.Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
            exe.initWithPath(path);
            var run = window.Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
            run.init(exe);
            var parameters = [""];
            run.run(false, parameters, parameters.length);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex.toString());
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:RunExe('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c start winword.exe');">Open Word</a>
</body>
```

Comment: I hope this code doesn't work in any sane browser, even if the html is stored locally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In javascript literals, a backslash indicates the beginning of an escape sequence.  If you actually want to represent a backslash, you can escape it with a double backslash.

ie
'**C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe** /c start winword.exe'

http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/escapesequence.shtml

EDIT:
From the comments on the correct answer from the post you linked, it looks like the way he got it working was:

only pass the path to runexe: 
**javascript:RunExe('C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe')**

set the params equal to the command args: 
**var parameters = ["/c start winword.exe"];**

So this would work theoretically:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function RunExe(path) {
    try {            
        var ua = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
        if (ua.indexOf("msie") != -1) {
            MyObject = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
            MyObject.Run(path);
        } else {
            netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");

            var exe = window.Components.classes['@mozilla.org/file/local;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsILocalFile);
            exe.initWithPath(path);
            var run = window.Components.classes['@mozilla.org/process/util;1'].createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIProcess);
            run.init(exe);
            var parameters = ["/c start winword.exe"];
            run.run(false, parameters, parameters.length);
        }
    } catch (ex) {
        alert(ex.toString());
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" onclick="javascript:RunExe('C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe');">Open Word</a>
</body>
```

Although clearly it would be better to pass in the params as an argument than hardcode them as I've done here (or pass them in as part of the path and parse them out)

Comment: Is that still true if he uses single quote?

Comment: @Amir Yes, it is the same for double or single quotes.

Comment: I see whered my backslash go. Shouldn't it then not be working?

Comment: @Rebol, I wish I had a Windows box to test this. :(

Comment: @Amir: There is a backslash in both of the literal strings, you do not see it in either of the alerts.

Comment: @Amir no chance for me that you're such a pure Linux Guy :)

Comment: @Rebol Reading the post that you linked, the comments below the correct answer indicate that he is not passing the command line arguments in as part of the path, but using them to explicitly set the params.

Comment: Well I took into account the comment but seems I didn't understand ... as well as I don't understand your comment can you put this into code thanks :)

Comment: @Rebol: edited into the original answer, basically just pass the path in to the RunExe call, and assign the stuff following the path to the params array that's currently just getting set to a blank string.

Comment: @kekela cheers I don't understand why it works but it does thanks so much :)