# Firefox add-ons: 1) Linking Python script to add-on main code | 2) win32 api in JPM / NPM | 3) set file attributes in Windows with OS.file

Tags: python, firefox-addon, filesystems, file-attributes

I would like to use the [win32 API](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_API) to create an hidden file on Windows OS.
It seems impossible using JS / Node.js.

With Python, importing the API, it is possible (using [SetFileAttributes](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) routine and FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN parameter).

So how can I link a Python script to the main JS code for my Firefox add-on? Can you please give me some reference about this matter? I've found nothing on the web.

Comment: Could you not just use the [standard Windows command line tool `ATTRIB`](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb490868.aspx)?  Importing an entire LANGUAGE *just* to do this seems like overkill.

Comment: I wish it were possible. That is for the dos prompt command in Windows. How to make it available to the js code of an add-on for Firefox?

Comment: Also, what is the reason you cannot just use [`SetFileAttributes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365535%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) via the [win32api](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32api) module?
Since ["*the **entire** `win32` API is available in node*"](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=4800077)?

Comment: Node.js don't have native methods to calling winapi functions.

Comment: Is there some reason you specifically need a *hidden file* (on windows).  what about Mac/Linux users of your extension?  And Android?  Why not use the [Firefox WebExtensions API for storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage) - which will work across platform?

Comment: I use the old-fashioned way: XPCOM and XUL-based add-ons,

Comment: Can you confirm rhe win32 api module is available in jpm?

Comment: Even in XPCOM you still have access to the [OSFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File.Info#Windows) API in recent browsers?  It has `winAttributes` **including** `hidden`.

Comment: "available in jpm" Do you mean npm?  I already [linked the win32api npm module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/win32api)?  It says it has the entire win32 API, which would *include* `SetFileAttributes`.  But you can also just use the Windows-specific part of [OSFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File.Info#Windows)?  that way you don't have to figure-out some connection between your extension and node.

Comment: So I believe that the only solution is to use the API. OS.file unfortunately only gives information about * existing* files. The storage object instead should be specific to one page (HTML document), in particular the opened one in the browser: I need a file to verify a general data and do not know a priori which page is active. In * nix systems hiding is not the problem, in fact you know that you just have just to put the "." to make it hidden.

Comment: Ahhh, now I start to see I think.  So you just want a non-browsing (*i.e.* page related) way of storing **state** information for the extension?  And the reason Windows needs this specifically is because of the \*nix convention making the name hide the file.  I get it.  I think you will have to use the old [File I/O](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/Code_snippets/File_I_O) to actually *create* the file, and then perhaps on Windows use [OSFile](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/OSFile.jsm/OS.File.Info#Windows) to just change it to `hidden`.

Comment: Yes, the logic is the one that you have said:  having memory for a value of state, not knowing a priori which will be the status of the browser when the value will be necessary. For the rest, can you please explain me why you insist to suggest OS.file? as I had said, it provides statistical information about the file (i.e. reading operations): It does not seem it can set that information ( i.e. write the attribute to change it).

Comment: Hmm true, true. You would be able to *check* the hidden attribute using OSFile.  Perhaps for modifying it you could use my first comment and go with [the `ATTRIB` command-line tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-au/library/bb490868.aspx)?
[This question here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6177583/how-to-open-exe-with-javascript-xpcom-as-windows-run) seems to indicate that you can use XPCOM's [XPConnect](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Tech/XPCOM/Language_bindings/XPConnect) to essentially launch a command shell and pass it a command.

Comment: @Tersosauros was on the right track to recommend `OS.File` :) See posted solution. :)

Comment: I read with interest your comments. I had just installed the api32 by following your link, and now I was going to test them. It also seems that your first suggestion was correct: you should be able to start the command line and then use  attrib to change the visibility to the file. (Useful your comment to generalize the path.). I did not know that was possible with JS for add-ons having all this interaction with the system. Can you give me a reference to learn about these options and proper syntax - e.g. the call from code to the command line(on MDN I didnt find these arguments)? much obliged.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XPCOM is going to be deprecated. While this can be accomplished with `nsIFile` I don't show it here because the performance is worse for the main thread. The recommended way for file system access right now is `OS.File.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript_OS.File/OS.File_for_the_main_thread

### Hidden files/directories on windows

This is how you do it with OS.File:

```
OS.File.setPermissions(
        OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'my hidden file.txt'),
          {
            winAttributes: {
                hidden: true
            }
        }
)
.then(x => console.log('success:', x), y => console.error('failure:', y));
```

This will set the file on the deskto named `my hidden file.txt` to be hidden. Here are the other `winAttributes`:

https://dxr.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/components/osfile/modules/osfile_win_front.jsm#1204-1227

### Hidden files/directories on *nix/Mac

Rename or create the file to have a `.` as the first chracter in its name and it is hidden. Using OS.File this is done with the `OS.File.move` function as rename is just a move on the file system:

```
OS.File.move(
        OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, 'my hidden file.txt'),
        OS.Path.join(OS.Constants.Path.desktopDir, '.my hidden file.txt')
)
.then(x => console.log('success:', x), y => console.error('failure:', y));
```

This will rename, and thus making it hidden, the file on the desktop from `my hidden file.txt` to `.my hidden file.txt`.

### Platform APIs

If you need to tap into the platform APIs, no need for python. We have js-ctypes:

Here are some docs on js-ctypes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/js-ctypes/Standard_OS_Libraries

And here is a library/collection of type and function declarations:

https://github.com/Noitidart/ostypes/issues/1#issuecomment-199492249

Comment: Very nice answer!  I was sure the Python/win32 API approach was too much just for this.

Comment: Beautiful answer! The second link was what I was missing!

Comment: Thanks guys! I added how to rename on Linux/Mac with `OS.File` you have to use `OS.File.move` it might not be intuitive that a rename operation is just a move operation on the file system.